# JVM Reuse MapReduce 2.0 YARN

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, jvm, hadoop-yarn

I have a large number of input splits (about 50.000) created by small files that I want to process with Hadoop. I have, however, only 256 containers available to process it.

The job itself uses lots of CPU but considerable little memory.

I am using Hadoop 2.3 and was taking a look in the JVM reuse feature from MapReduce 1.0

I have also read about uber tasks, but it didn't look like the same thing - or I had a different understand from JVM reuse.

Since I have lots of small files (and am generating a inputSplit per file), I wanted to create a single JVM machine per container and run as many sequential Map tasks as possible per already allocated JVM. This would reduce the JVM allocating time overhead.

I guess that for each input split a new mapper would be allocated and thus a new JVM, am I right?

How can i do such thing in YARN?

Oh, I know that also I can use compressing in order to increase the inputSplit size, but for this exact application this is not viable.

Best Regards,
Marco Lotz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. In yarn, the tasks run in a dedicated JVM. And unlike mapreduce 1, it doesn't support JVM reuse.

In mapreduce 1 however, the property for controlling task JVM reuse is `mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks`. It
specifies the maximum number of tasks to run for a given job for each JVM launched and by default it is `1`.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10486309/1101823) should give you a better idea about JVM reuse in 1.